# Error: No component factory found for BarChartComponent in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for BarChartComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

```
ngOnInit() {

this.sidenavdropdownservice.getJson()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.list = data;

    for(let i of data) {
      for(let j of i.subMenu) {
        for(let a in j.url) {
          console.log('path : ' + j.url[a].path)
          //this.router.config.push({path : j.url[a].path , component : j.url[a].component});
          this.ROUTES.push({path : j.url[a].path , component : j.url[a].component});
          this.router.resetConfig(this.ROUTES);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

}

Comment: please add your code

Comment: did you add BarChartComponent to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Comment: yes i added it in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

Check your app.module.ts.

You should put your page in @NgMogule.

```
 @NgModule({
      declarations: [
           YourPage,
               ],
    entryComponents: [
    YourPage,
              ]
```

I had the same erro, in my case was that problem.